# Capturing errors in user's browser for postmortem debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

We get reports from our users about blank pages and other errors in our web application that are too vague to help us narrow down the problem. We can ask them (usually without much success) to install Fiddler to capture the HTTP traffic, but more often than not, it's a JavaScript error, not something in the data sent from our servers.

My ideal solution would be a browser extension that could capture HTTP traffic, JavaScript errors and other console output, the state of the DOM, screenshots, and anything else useful for postmortem debugging. The extension should phone the data home to us, with the user's permission. Better still, extensions for Firefox, Chrome, and IE (and Safari and Opera).

Are there even partial solutions out there? The only thing that I've found so far is BITE, http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2011/10/take-bite-out-of-bugs-and-redundant.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.exceptionhub.com/ is a service that does this kind of thing.

Browser cannot take screenshots of themselves without a plug-in though.

Answer (score 0):

As for javascript errors, you should really consider installing an exception handler into your javascript app, that could report errors (stacktraces) to the server. If you dont want to rely on 3rd parties, you can use sentry for example.

I agree, that sometimes this is not a solution. If you have a complex client side application, its features can break without any exception... Sadly, I havent found any useful plugins for capturing exact dynamic state of the page.

As from more like a theoretical/proof-of-concept side, DAVID PACHECO has an [interesting writing](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2039361) on postmortem debugging in dynamic envs (like js, or java, python).

---

Links related to sentry:

- http://getsentry.com
- https://github.com/getsentry/sentry (Server source code - in python/django)
- https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js (Javascript client module)